# Select distinct but group them by 24 hours?

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright so I'm creating articles. Everytime an user opens the article, their IP, article id and date gets saved into MySQL.

```
$date = time();
$sql = "INSERT INTO views(ip,article,date) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_GET['id'],$date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now, I want to get unique views and I know how to do this with DISTINCT. But this isn't entirely what I want to do. It will get unique views of all time, but I want each user's view to count for every 24 hours.

Say I'm person A and there's person B. We both view the article. Total unique views will be 2. Tomorrow I view the article again, it'll still show 2 views, but I want it to show 3 views because it has been 24 hours.

I can do this by checking if they have viewed the article therefore not adding their view count to the database, but I don't want to do this. I need an alternative way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, but if the `date` is of data type datetime, then you need to group by the date part only, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATE) AS Date, article, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS TotalViews
FROM views 
WHERE article = $articleId
  AND DATE>= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY  CAST(date AS DATE), article
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is too confusing. Where do I put the article ID so it knows which article to get views of? I'm a beginner to MySQL, thank you for the quick reply! Appreciate it.

Comment: @jarlh - It deserves a downvote Sorry, just the copy and paste :D

Comment: Just tried and I got this error: https://i.imgur.com/Co6XyLU.png What's wrong? :(

Comment: @RRecords it was my fault, you have to remove the alias from the group by, try my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it and I believe it worked. Is there a way to modify if let's say I want the views from past week grouped by 24 hours?

Comment: I don't think it works. I have 5 unique IPs viewing one article. I viewed the article twice and changed my date to 2 days ago, yet it shows 5 views.

Answer (score 0):

> I want each user's view to count for every 24 hours.

Just use two arguments to `count(distinct)`:

```
select article, count(distinct ip, date(date))
from v
group by article;
```

If you want a separate result *for each day*, then put the date logic in the `group by`:

```
select article, date(date), count(distinct ip)
from v
group by article, date(date);
```

However, that doesn't seem to be the question you are asking.

Comment: @RRecords . . . A remarkably unhelpful comment.  You should explain how it doesn't work.